# Delete rows with conditions on some columns

Tags: matlab

I would like to delete all the repeated rows ignoring the contents of the 2nd column
I have used this code : `x = unique(x,'rows');`
without success;

Thank you for your help.

```
A=
1   x   10  4
1   x   10  4
1   x   10  4
2   x   20  5
2   x   15  5
3   x   30  6
4   x   50  7
4   x   50  7
5   x   60  8
5   x   60  8
5   x   65  9

Result 
A = 
1   x   10  4
2   x   20  5
2   x   15  5
3   x   30  6
4   x   50  7
5   x   60  8
5   x   65  9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the multiple-output version of `unique` to get the row indices:

```
[bb ii jj] = unique(A(:,[1 3:end]),'rows');
result = A(ii,:);
```

This is essentially the same as @RobertP.'s answer, which came 6 seconds earlier :-)

Comment: Luis: I think you need to switch around the indices in `A` for this to be right.

Comment: @user2991439: Accepting an answer is the best way to thank someone =) It's the check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
[~, idx] = unique(A(:,[1 3 4]),'rows')

B = A(idx,:)
```